# Is it true that the entire substrate docs points to an archived repo?

Tags: pallet, error, documentation

The [substrate docs](https://docs.substrate.io/) are supposed to guide users through the substrate SDK via tutorials. [These tutorials](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/) use exclusively (to my knowledge) the [substrate node template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) repository. However, all the packages and libraries inside of that repo (at least all the branches i have checked including *main*) point to this outdated substrate repository (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate). For instance the [runtime library](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/runtime/Cargo.toml) or the [pallets](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/pallets/template/Cargo.toml). I do not know which repo replaces the substrate repo, but i suspect [this one](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk)? How do people learn Substrate if the entire docs are outdated to the extend that all the tutorials wont even compile or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, the [repo](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk) you've pointed is the correct currently active monorepo. The [node-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) that you've pointed to as an example is also actively maintained and functional. All of the tutorials seem to be pointing to `polkadot-sdk` repo like in [this one](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/prepare-a-local-relay-chain/). Would be great if you could share a specific outdated reference if you find one.

Comment: Thanks @philoniare. For instance I am trying to follow the https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/collectibles-workshop/ 
There (https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/collectibles-workshop/runtime-and-pallets/) it says I have to checkout branch "polkadot-v1.0.0", but polkadot-sdk doesnt event have that branch, maybe i have to checkout https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/tree/mergebase-polkadot-v1.0.0  but there is such a branch on 
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-v1.0.0

Comment: Then it tells me to set up my node_template (https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/collectibles-workshop/01-prepare/) which points to https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/tags/ and the Quick-start link leads me to 404. The entire 'substrate-node-template' points to the outdated repo, see for instance here: https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/node/Cargo.toml

Comment: The entire substrate-node-template points to the outdated repo. Every branch that I checked out points to it. For instance on main the run-time crates https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/runtime/Cargo.toml , the node-crates (see above) and the pallet creates https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/pallets/template/Cargo.toml point to old repo. Of course i could try to swap out the deprecated code manually and I tried, but the dependence jungle is too deep for a novice. If I wasnt a noob, I wouldnt visit the tutorial.